# Garage Band automatically decrease down the volume in MIDI tracks

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, garage-band

I'm trying to use a MIDI Controller **M-Audio Keystation 49e** (connected via USB) in Garage Band but when I start playing, the volume is automatically decreased down

[image: Volume Issue with MIDI in Garage Band]

Is this normal? Is this a problem with my MIDI Controller?
Are there any settings I can adjust to prevent this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You've probably got a volume level recorded in the midi. idk how you do event editing in GB so I can't help further, sorry.

Comment: Or you've added some volume automation...

Comment: @BobBroadley, that's not the case. In the GIF you can see how the volume automation (horizontal yellow line on the right) is behaving

Answer (score 0):

i use the exact same keyboard and have the same issue. i noticed it was always the same keys doing that. but even after opening up the keyboard and looking at the PCB i couldnt find any obvious problems with it (keep in mind i have no idea what im doing im just looking for visual cues like rust or wtv) but yeah the best solution is to figure out what keys are causing it and just not playing them. then adjusting in piano roll for it to be the right note.